# Include Python Code In Excel?

Tags: python, excel

I'd like to be able to include `python` code snippets in `Excel` (ideally, in a nice format -- all colors/formats should be kept the same).

What would be the best way to go about it?

**EDIT**: I just want to store `python` code in an Excel spreadsheet for an easy overview -- I am not going to run it -- just want it to be nicely visible/formatted as part of an `Excel` worksheet.

Comment: Do you want to store the python code in a worksheet?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to archive, do you want run the python in excel?

Comment: I just want to store the `python` code in a worksheet (say, in a *textbox*), for reference purposes and easy overview of the code.
I want the code to be easy to view, with colors etc.

Comment: Why?  Excel seems to be an incredibly poor tool for code review.

Comment: This isn't a python question.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: for tiny code snippets, it's perfect! do you have any suggestions how to achieve what I am trying to do? any other suggestions?

Comment: How about gist.github.com? It might be exactly what you are looking for (minus the excel.)

Comment: @FarmBoy  Write that as an answer and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [gist](https://gist.github.com/) (from github) is precisely what you are looking for. From the description:

> Gist is a simple way to share snippets
>   and pastes with others.  All gists are
>   git repositories, so they are
>   automatically versioned,  forkable and
>   usable as a git repository.

Comment: I really which things could be embedded into `Excel`, but if I can't find a solution, this is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

While Excel itself doesnot support other scripting Langauges than VBA, the open source OpenOffice and LibreOffice packages - which include a spreadsheet - can be scriptable with Python. Still, they won't allow Python code to be pasted on teh cells out of the box - but it is possible to write Python code which can act on the spredsheet contents (and do all the other things Python can do).